# R convert time (xx:xx:xx) to min. as.POSIXct returns error "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

Tags: r

I have some data about focus times in xx:xx:xx format that I would like to add together over several sessions. So I am trying to convert each of them to minutes or any format that can be summed and understood. I've tried as.POSIX.ct but I get the error in the title. I've also tried lubidate hms(day1)/60 and I get another error. Here's a shortened reproducible example.

```
day1 <- c("01:05:38", "00:56:54", "00:48:17")
day2 <- c("00:37:57", "00:21:09", "00:43:34")
day1convert <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(day1), units = "mins")
```

This returns the error: "Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

```
library(lubridate)
convert<-hms(day1)/60
```

This returns the error:"Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “Period” object: periods must have integer values

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what is your expected output but you can try the following to get time in minutes.

```
library(lubridate)
period_to_seconds(hms(day1))/60
#[1] 65.63333 56.90000 48.28333
```

If you want to convert time to `POSIXct` format

```
as.POSIXct(day1, format = "%T", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2020-02-15 01:05:38 UTC" "2020-02-15 00:56:54 UTC" "2020-02-15 00:48:17 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```r
sapply(strsplit(day1, ":"), function(x) as.difftime(sum(c(60, 1, 1/60)*as.numeric(x)), units="mins"))
#> [1] 65.63333 56.90000 48.28333
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) chron::times** Use chron `times` class. They can be added and if we convert them to numeric they are given in fractions of a day.

```
library(chron)

times(day1) + times(day2)
## [1] 01:43:35 01:18:03 01:31:51

as.numeric(times(day1) + times(day2))
## [1] 0.07193287 0.05420139 0.06378472
```

**2) data.table::as.ITime**  Another possibility is data.table's `ITime`.   They can be added or converting to numeric gives seconds.

```
library(data.table)

as.ITime(day1) + as.ITime(day2)
## [1] "01:43:35" "01:18:03" "01:31:51"

as.numeric(as.ITime(day1) + as.ITime(day2))
## [1] 6215 4683 5511
```